# Setup P2-Repository on own Server for Eclipse Plugins

Tags: eclipse, server, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, p2

I want to use a P2-Repository to manage Eclipse Plugins. I have a Windows Server 2008 machine. But I have absolutely no idea what I have to do. 
What do I have to do on my PC in Eclipse and what on the server to make everything work? Can anyone of you guys help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P2 repository has its own layout and structure.
Use [tycho maven plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/) to create P2 repository on your server using one of its goal, [assemble repository](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-p2/tycho-p2-repository-plugin/assemble-repository-mojo.html)

Hope this helps. If you are not suing tycho, start using it. Life will be easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Let me know if this works. Please accept the answer so that it will help others.